# Work around for Anemic domain model pattern

Tags: asp.net, .net

A domain model that does not contain the business logic for the model is considered an anti-pattern by some -

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model

But in some applications, such as .NET applications, seem to prefer a model with out business logic.

Would the following be a good implementation of combining these two concepts.

Have a base model, with the constructor and all "set" statements defined as **protected**, then have a class that inherits from that base class, which implements the business logic for the base class and helps create the base object. The base model could then be used for something like an MVC View.

Base class -

```
public class Customer
{
    protected Customer()
    {
    }
    public string FirstName { get; protected set; }

    public string LastName { get; protected set; }

    public int Age { get; protected set; }

}
```

Inheriting class -

```
public class CustomerCreator : Customer
{
    public void SetFirstName(string firstName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public void SetLastName(string lastName)
    {
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string SetAge(int age)
    {
        string result = "";

        if (age < 18)
        {
            return "can't be less than 18";
        }

        this.Age = age;

        return result;
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Are there any potential hazards to this pattern?
Is this a pattern that is already commonly used?

Comment: "Would the following be a good implementation of combining these two concepts.": this statement/question is unclear (at least to me).  Exactly which two concepts are you trying to combine?  The only concept the question discussed up to that point is an Anemic Domain Model.  What's the second concept?  Non-anemic Domain Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're really buying yourself anything here. Ultimately casting to `Customer` via the `GetCustomer()` method doesn't actually change anything in terms of the ability to get properties on the model. You're still indirectly robbing your customer of its own business logic with the derived `CustomerCreator` class. I think you're better off placing your logic in the class you expect to work with (ie `Customer`) and creating a projection in the form of a viewmodel or DTO for displaying data to the client. Try something like this for your domain model:

```
public class Customer
{
    private int _age;

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age
    {
        get => _age;
        set
        {
            if (value < 18)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(Age), "can't be less than 18");
            }
            _age = value;
        }
    }


    protected Customer() { }
}
```

A couple of additional points:

- I'd recommend avoiding restricting access on your properties unnecessarily. In the case of `FirstName` and `LastName` there are no invariants attached to them so the protected setters are not only confusing, but require additional unnecessary indirection to work with. This could also be confusing in the future if other devs (or you after some time away to forget) question why the accessibility was limited to begin with. Going from less to more restricted access modifiers can be done when business rules demand it and it's a relatively safe operation- almost all issues that can arise as a result of restricting access will do so at design time. Going from more restrictive to less restrictive access should always be done with an abundance of caution- if a property/field/method/etc is less than public then hopefully it was designed that way with good reason. Overlooking those reasons can lead the circumvention of invariants, which can lead to runtime issues, inconsistent system state, and corrupt data.

- There is nothing particular to C#/.NET that requires or recommends anemic models. Many developers write their models that way and then act upon them with a variety of services, but that general pattern is not necessary by any means nor is it specific to C#. The teams I have worked with implement rich models that are directly persisted and rehydrated via ORMs such as Entity Framework and while it sometimes requires making concessions due the the quirks of a particular ORM, it always ends up working well.

Comment: I totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a [builder pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern) a pattern that's a part of a more broadly defined set of [creational patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern#:%7E:text=%20Some%20examples%20of%20creational%20design%20patterns%20include%3A,of%20a%20complex%20object%20from%20its...%20More%20). The most obvious examples are builders such as [StringBuilder](https://www.bing.com/newtabredir?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.text.stringbuilder) and [UriBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=net-5.0).

There's a few problems with a builder pattern on the entity side of things in the DDD world, and in particular your current implementation.

First, builders are suitable for value objects, which are fungible and can have value even if not complete (e.g. just a street address with no zip code). For entities, a factory would be more suitable because we want our entities to *always be valid* (see this great [blog entry](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/always-valid-domain-model/) by Vladimir Khorikov). A factory doesn't turn out an incomplete car, for example; no one would buy that car because, well, it's not a car yet!

Second, your example uses inheritance, and mixes concepts. Let's examine this.

**(Wrong) Alternatives**

Inheritance models an *is-a* relationship. Ask yourself, "Is a `CustomerBuilder` a `Customer`?" The answer is no; you can say a `HouseBuilder` (a person) is not a `House` so inheritance is not appropriate here. It's the same with customers.

You're also not going to do this using composition, which models a *has-a* relationship. Does a `CustomerBuilder` have a `Customer`? No. By analogy, a `HouseBuilder` does not *have* a house, a house builder makes a house. Aside: the builder might live in a house, and thus own one, but how does that have anything to do with building some other house?

**Creational Patterns**

So, the most natural relationship here is a creational one, and in particular a factory. In your case you'd want a customer factory that *creates* a customer. It accepts all the inputs such as name, age, and so on, and when finally ready to create the customer, it constructs the customer all at once, completely and correctly. If the final customer is not meant to have things like name or age changes, these properties could be made get-only.

What's important here, is that if you *extend* customer with a builder as you were doing, you could allow that customer to be changed incorrectly; this is antithetical to DDD. Worse, you've got the confusion between the thing being built and the thing doing the building.

**Refinements**

Ok, so what if your domain allows a customer to age or their name to change? You don't want unfettered write access to these properties. Consider this example: ***John Doe*** is ***21*** years old. Some piece of calling code sets the first name to *Mike* and then the age to ***30*** one year later! Makes no sense. Not only is your entity anemic (no internal logic), the logic is external to your domain and allows for time travel!

Let's instead make your `Customer` less anemic, and provide sensible rules or policies:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
    {
        ...
    }

    public string FirstName { get; private set; }

    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public void AgeByOneYear()
        => Age += 1;

    public void ChangeFirstName(string newName, IRenamingPolicy renamingPolicy) 
        => FirstName = renamingPolicy.ValidateName(newName);
    ...
}
```

**Relationship of the Factory/Builder to the Domain**

In DDD, factories are part of the domain, but not the domain model itself. At this point you may ask, "Well, wait. This factory has domain logic in it, shouldn't that be in the domain model?"

Good question. The answer is yes, and this will make your domain model less anemic. Another aside: you can have entities in your domain model that don't have much (if any) internal logic without your model being considered anemic. As long as the business/domain logic is in your DDD model, and not in your orchestration, persistence, or other layers, you can skate by the *anemic* label. This is what I did by externalizing renaming logic in a policy, but effecting the renaming action in the `Customer`. The `RenamingPolicy` *contains* domain logic and *is* part of your domain.

**Final Thoughts**

- Anemic models (or not) and creational patterns are orthogonal concepts, but I've shown how thinking of them together can lead to a  coherent domain model.
- Using a `Customer` entity (even if it was a base class of some kind) is probably not a good idea to use as an MVC view or view model. The needs are different; an entity has behavior in a domain whereas a view model *is* anemic and expresses properties that are bound to a view for presentation.
- If your experience is that .NET domain models are anemic, I'd say that's anecdotal and shouldn't set precedent. For simple apps, that's fine; for rich enterprise apps, you might be looking at a bad design.

Comment: Just for clarity, builder pattern typically implies granular/incremental building of the object in question vs factory pattern which spits out an instance in one go. I think OP is somewhat coincidentally implementing the builder pattern but for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @joelmdev true. I was focusing on the final result. In DDD we can't have an incremental (partially complete) entity.

Comment: @joelmdev actually, your point is well taken. I'll update this with a focus on factory over builder precisely because an entity can only be an entity if it meets certain invariants.

Answer (score 0):

A model is anemic if you are using it to just store/carry data and keeping business logic related to it in some other place.

In your example you are inheriting a class purely to create Customer object in a specific way but it's not really protecting any in-variance other than supporting a style of writing code. While I refrain to say something is wrong because there might be a reason behind it, I fail to see a valid one here.

Two main purpose of a language supporting inheritance, in my opinion/understanding are:

- Code reuse
- Encapsulation - indirect

If you really want to protect how a Customer Object can be instantiated, you could have a static factory method on the Customer class itself. However that doesn't make that model 'rich'.

Difference between 'rich' and 'anemic' is where you decide to keep the business logic - outside of your domain entities (aggregates to be precise but will go with entity for simplicity) or as an operation on domain entities.

If you consider your system as a series of coordinated state changes of entities, you have a choice where you keep the logic of that state change. In rich model you include it as an operation on the entity itself so you have tighter control maintaining the invariant.